# Find the degree $[E:\mathbb{Q}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, splitting-field

Let $p$ a prime number. Find a splitting field $E$ of the polynomial $x^p-2 \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$.

I have done the following:

The solutions of $x^p-2=0$ are :
$$\sqrt[p]{2}, \sqrt[p]{2}\omega, \dots, \sqrt[p]{2}\omega^{p-1}, \text{ where } \omega=e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{p}}$$

Therefore, the splitting field is $E=\mathbb{Q(\sqrt[p]{2}, \omega)}$

Is this correct so far??

How can I find the degree $[E:\mathbb{Q}]$ ??

**EDIT:**

$[E:\mathbb{Q}]=[\mathbb{Q(\sqrt[p]{2}, \omega)} : \mathbb{Q}]=[\mathbb{Q(\sqrt[p]{2}, \omega)} : \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2})][\mathbb{Q(\sqrt[p]{2})} : \mathbb{Q}]=[\mathbb{Q(\sqrt[p]{2}, \omega)} : \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2})]p$

Since $Irr(\sqrt[p]{2}, \mathbb{Q})=x^p-2 \Rightarrow [\mathbb{Q(\sqrt[p]{2})} : \mathbb{Q}]=p$.

But how can we find $[\mathbb{Q(\sqrt[p]{2}, \omega)} : \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2})]$ ??

**EDIT: Proof that the degree is the product of p and p-1:**

$$[\mathbb{Q}(\omega, \sqrt[p]{2}) :\mathbb{Q}]=[\mathbb{Q}(\omega, \sqrt[p]{2}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2})][\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2}):\mathbb{Q}]=a \cdot p$$

$$[\mathbb{Q}(\omega, \sqrt[p]{2}):\mathbb{Q}]=[\mathbb{Q}(\omega, \sqrt[p]{2}):\mathbb{Q}(\omega)][\mathbb{Q}(\omega):\mathbb{Q}]=b \cdot (p-1)$$

$$a \cdot p = b \cdot (p-1) \Rightarrow p \mid a \cdot p \overset{(p, p-1)=1}{ \Longrightarrow } p \mid b \Rightarrow p \leq b \tag 1 $$ $$\Rightarrow a \cdot p \leq a \cdot b \Rightarrow b \cdot (p-1) \leq a \cdot b \Rightarrow p-1 \leq a \tag 2 $$

$$\mathbb{Q} \leq \mathbb{Q}(\omega) \leq \mathbb{Q}(\omega, \sqrt[p]{2}) \Rightarrow Irr(\sqrt[p]{2}, \mathbb{Q}(\omega)) \mid Irr(\sqrt[p]{2}, \mathbb{Q}) $$ $$\Rightarrow \deg Irr(\sqrt[p]{2}, \mathbb{Q}(\omega)) \leq \deg Irr(\sqrt[p]{2}, \mathbb{Q}) \Rightarrow b \leq p \tag 3$$

$$\mathbb{Q} \leq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2}) \leq \mathbb{Q}(\omega, \sqrt[p]{2}) \Rightarrow Irr(\omega, \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2})) \mid Irr(\omega, \mathbb{Q}) $$ $$ \Rightarrow \deg Irr(\omega, \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2})) \leq \deg Irr(\omega, \mathbb{Q}) \Rightarrow a \leq p-1 \tag 4$$

From $(1)$ and $(3)$ we have that $b=p$ and from $(2)$ and $(4)$ we have that $a=p-1$

Therefore, $[\mathbb{Q}(\omega, \sqrt[p]{2}) :\mathbb{Q}]=p(p-1)$.

Comment: Since splitting fields are unique, we talk about *the* splitting field.

Comment: You mean $\sqrt[p]2$, right?

Comment: Yes, I edited my post...

Comment: What is $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2}) : \mathbb{Q}]$?

Comment: @Kaj People sometimes say "a" splitting field because the splitting field is not unique up to *unique* isomorphism. Two splitting fields are not canonically isomorphic.

Comment: @BrunoJoyal, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @DanielFischer I edited my post... Do you have an idea how we could find this degree??

Comment: @BrunoJoyal I edited my post... Do you have an idea how to calculate this degree??

Answer (score 2):

You've done most of the work for yourself, and your proposed splitting field is correct.

We can consider two towers of fields:
$$\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[p]{2}] \subset \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[p]{2}, \omega]$$
$$\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q}[\omega] \subset \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[p]{2}, \omega]$$
 where $\omega$ is a $p^{\text{th}}$ root of unity.

In the first tower, the intermediate field is of degree $p$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ (Why?).  In the second tower, the intermediate field is of degree $p-1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. (again, why?)

Now apply the fact that $[K:F] = [K:E] \cdot [E:F]$ for a tower of fields $F \subset E \subset K$.  Given this, both $p$ and $p-1$ divide the degree of the splitting field.  Further, the degree of the splitting field is *at most* $p(p-1)$ since, worst case scenario, the minimal polynomial for $\sqrt[p]{2}$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}[\omega]$.

Therefore...

Comment: $Irr(\sqrt[p]{2},\mathbb{Q})=x^p−2$, it is irreducible since its roots are not in $\mathbb{Q}$. So, $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2}),\mathbb{Q}]=p$. Is this correct?? $$$$ Applying Eisenstein's criterion, do we not show that a polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$?? But we want to show that it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2})$...

Comment: I edited my initial post... Do you have an idea how we can find this degree?? Using Eisenstein criterion we show that a polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ and not over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[p]{2})$...

Comment: @Mary, use the following argument. There are two intermediate fields of interest $K_1=\Bbb{Q}(\root p\of 2)$ and $K_2=\Bbb{Q}(\omega)$. The former is a degree $p$ extension of the rationals, the latter a degree $p-1$ extension. By multiplicative of the degree in a tower, you can deduce that $[E:\Bbb{Q}]$ has to be a multiple of both $p$ and $p-1$. Because the least common multiple of $p$ and $p-1$ is their product,...

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Ok... Do I have to prove that the degree is equal to this product?? I tried to prove it... I will add it at my initial post... Could you tell me if it is correct??

Comment: Looks ok, @Mary.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Ok... Thank you very much!!! :-)

Comment: Kaj, could you explain to me further the last sentence?? I got stuck right now...